# Strange behaviour of query in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I dunno, why hibernate sends a queries in depends how many id i will get from this select "SELECT max(gps2.id) from GPSPositions gps2 group by gps2.user". If i get two ids, hibernate will send three select's. One main query for gps and two queries to above id's ?? And how can i optymalize this query that hibernate alwasy send one query in depends of number of ids.

i will be very gratefully for any help.
BTW - query is send to oracle

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("
    From GPSPositions gps 
    WHERE gps.user <> 0 " +
    AND ( (substring(gps.szerokoscGeograficzna,0,1) <> 0) OR (substring(gps.dlugoscGeograficzna, 0,1) <> 0)) +
    AND (gps.czasBazy) > sysdate - 50/(24*60) 
    AND gps.id IN (SELECT max(gps2.id) from GPSPositions gps2 group by gps2.user)
    ORDER BY gps.szerokoscGeograficzna
");
```

Comment: Tally accurately how the corresponding SQL statement should look like and what statement is generated based on the supplied parameters. The query should work fine apart from the native database function `sysdate` which belongs to Oracle.

Comment: "sysdate" is not valid JPQL. "CURRENT_DATE" is.